# Mixing frames and autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

[image: Sketch]

> **TL; DR;**
>
> How to update *self* frame height from layoutSubviews() and propagate new frame size to AutoLayout outside of *self*?

I have a component (let's say tags cloud), a height of the component calculates automatically based on a width. For a better performance (and less code in my case) I do positioning and height calculation manually with using frames. Outside the component is placed with using AutoLayout in a UITableViewCell.

I don't know how to update intrinsic content size to reflect this in a UITableViewCell layout correctly. When I calculate a height (= set and invalidate intrinsic size) right in layoutSubview(), seems like it's too late. I see a result just on the next render cycle.

The component data (means height) can be changed dynamically at any moment. I think without embedding into UITableView everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: “I see a result just on the next render cycle” Call `super` both before and after your changes.

Comment: @matt It doesn't help.

Basically, I set the new frame size before super.layoutSubviews() and it works in the context of the component. But it doesn't update layout of a super view. Looks like it's not enough. If I call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() it obviously gives me an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, I remember there’s a WWDC talk on that sort of problem!

Comment: @matt Could you tell me which talk exactly? I will watch it. Thanks.